# Tkinter Non Y scroll header for XY scroll region

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am looking for a way to keep a static header for a table which can scroll on the X direction but not on the Y while being liked to a table which can scroll on both X and Y. (Like a spreadsheet where the column letters are always visible or when you freeze a row in google sheets).

For data cols = ["", ""] (list) and rows = [{"":"", "":""}, {"":"", "":""}](list of dictionaries)

Code:

```
    def table_scroll_Y(self, *args):
        self.table_title.yview
        self.table_data.yview
    def build_table(self, cols, data):
        for child in self.tablebase.winfo_children(): # Clear existing table
            child.pack_forget()
            child.destroy()
        colour1 = "#EEEEEE" # sets title colour
        rheight = 1 # sets row height
        rowsize = []

        #Note: self.tku.cFrame(**kwrds) =  Frame(*args) and frame.pack(*args)
        layout1=self.tku.cFrame(self.tablebase, side=LEFT,  fill=BOTH, expand=1, bg="white") #split between table area and scroll bar for fixed Y scroll
        self.Vscroll = Scrollbar(self.tablebase, orient="vertical")
        self.Vscroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        layout2 = self.tku.cFrame(layout1, side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1, bg="white") #split between table and bottom scroll for fixed X scroll
        self.Hscroll = Scrollbar(layout1, orient="horizontal")
        self.Hscroll.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

        self.table_title = Canvas(layout2, bg="red", highlightthickness=0, height=10) #X scroll area for Column titles
        self.table_data = Canvas(layout2, bg="blue", highlightthickness=0, yscrollcommand=self.Vscroll.set, xscrollcommand=self.Hscroll.set) # XY scroll area for table data
        self.Vscroll.config(command = self.table_scroll_Y) #configures command for Y on both scroll areas
        self.Hscroll.config(command = self.table_data.xview) #configure command for X on data scroll region

        #crate frames to hold all the widgets
        title_frame = Frame(self.table_title, bg="orange")
        title_frame.pack(padx=15, pady=15, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        data_frame = Frame(self.table_data, bg="purple")
        data_frame.pack(padx=15, pady=15, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        
        #create windows and pack widgets
        self.table_title.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.table_data.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.table_title.create_window(0,0, window=title_frame)
        self.table_data.create_window(0,0, window=data_frame)
        self.table_title.config(scrollregion=self.table_title.bbox("all"))
        self.table_data.config(scrollregion=self.table_data.bbox("all"))
        self.table_title.yview_moveto(0) 
        self.table_data.yview_moveto(0)
        self.table_data.xview_moveto(0)

        #Build table column headers
        row = self.tku.cFrame(title_frame, fill=X, borderwidth=1, relief="ridge", highlightbackground="black")
        for item in cols:
            Label(row, text=item, width=len(item)+1, borderwidth=2, relief="groove", heigh=rheight, bg=colour1).pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)
            rowsize.append(len(item)+1)

        #Build table data
        i = 0
        for datarow in data:
            row = self.tku.cFrame(data_frame, fill=X, borderwidth=1, relief="ridge", highlightbackground="black")
            for key, value in datarow.items():
                Label(row, text=value, width=rowsize[i], borderwidth=2, relief="groove", heigh=rheight, bg="white").pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)
                if i <= len(rowsize):
                    i = 0
                else:
                    i+=1
```

In my code the scrolls are in the right places but the widgets seem to be offset far left and off the top of the frame they are built in (self.tablebase is a standard Frame to hold all the table stuff).

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to rebind the scrollbars to their respective areas be replacing the command=canvas.xview with a full lambda function that binds it to both cavas objects and scrolls them together.

```
    def table_scroll_X(self, *args): # args = ('moveto', 0-1) and can be used with xview_moveto(pos) command
        self.table_title.xview_moveto(args[1])
        self.table_data.xview_moveto(args[1])
    def build_table(self, cols, data):
        # Clear existing widget so we have a fresh start (used for updating to a new table)
        for child in self.tablebase.winfo_children(): 
            child.pack_forget()
            child.destroy()
        ##---
        colour1 = "#EEEEEE" # sets title colour to a light gray colour
        rheight = 1 # sets row height
        rowsize = [] # used to keep row sizes uniform
        
        #Note: self.tku.cFrame(**kwrds) ==  'frame = Frame(*args)' and 'frame.pack(*args)' with 'return frame', used to make crating common widgets a little quicker.
        
        #split between table area and scroll bar for fixed Y scroll (Prevents scrolling the scrollbar off screen)
        layout1=self.tku.cFrame(self.tablebase, side=LEFT,  fill=BOTH, expand=1, bg="white") 
        self.Vscroll = Scrollbar(self.tablebase, orient="vertical")
        self.Vscroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        #split between table area and scroll bar for fixed X scroll
        layout2 = self.tku.cFrame(layout1, side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1, bg="white")
        self.Hscroll = Scrollbar(layout1, orient="horizontal")
        self.Hscroll.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        
        #create the Canvas objects that can be scrolled
        self.table_title = Canvas(layout2, bg="white", highlightthickness=0, height=25) #X scroll area for Column titles
        self.table_data = Canvas(layout2, bg="white", highlightthickness=0, yscrollcommand=self.Vscroll.set, xscrollcommand=self.Hscroll.set) # X/Y scroll area for table data
        self.Vscroll.config(command = self.table_data.yview) #configures command for Y only on the data (up/down)
        self.Hscroll.config(command = self.table_scroll_X) #configure command for X on data scroll region (left/right)
        
        #crate frames to hold all the widgets
        title_frame = Frame(self.table_title, bg="white")
        title_frame.pack(padx=15, pady=15, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        data_frame = Frame(self.table_data, bg="white")
        data_frame.pack(padx=15, pady=15, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        
        #create windows and pack widgets
        self.table_title.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=0, pady=0)
        self.table_data.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=0, pady=0)
        title_frame.bind("<Configure>",lambda e: self.table_title.configure(scrollregion=self.table_title.bbox("all")))
        data_frame.bind("<Configure>",lambda e: self.table_data.configure(scrollregion=self.table_data.bbox("all")))
        self.table_title.create_window(0,0, window=title_frame)
        self.table_data.create_window(0,0, window=data_frame)

        #Build table column headers
        row = self.tku.cFrame(title_frame, fill=X, borderwidth=1, relief="ridge", highlightbackground="black", side=LEFT)
        i = 0
        for item in cols:
            rowsize.append(math.ceil(len(item)*1.7)) # allows for some text size discrepencys.
            Label(row, text=item, font='TkFixedFont', width=rowsize[i], borderwidth=2, relief="groove", heigh=rheight, bg=colour1).pack(side=LEFT)
            if i <= len(rowsize):
                i=0
            else:
                i+=1
        #Build table data
        print(rowsize)
        i = 0
        for datarow in data:
            row = self.tku.cFrame(data_frame, fill=X, borderwidth=1, relief="ridge", highlightbackground="black")
            for key, value in datarow.items():
                Label(row, text=value, font='TkFixedFont', width=rowsize[i], borderwidth=2, relief="groove", heigh=rheight, bg="white").pack(side=LEFT)
                if i <= len(rowsize):
                    i=0
                else:
                    i+=1
        #update the interface to apply sizing and move all scrollbars to 0,0
        self.root.update()
        self.root.update_idletasks()
        self.table_title.yview_moveto(0) 
        self.table_data.yview_moveto(0)
        self.table_title.xview_moveto(0)
        self.table_data.xview_moveto(0)
```

This could be re-implemented into having scrollbars control multiple canvas objects if you want to freeze just a single row or column or both.